# How to replace special characters along with the text? like (.,*,/,\)

Tags: vim, vi

I am having a hierarchy name like `a.b.c.d.e` in multiple lines along with some text. Now I want to change that as `a/b/c/d/e`.

I tried `%s/\./\//g`. It did not work.

Error:Trailing Characters

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It works here. Did you type anything after the `g`?

Comment: No i did not type anything.

Comment: Weird. Can you post a screenshot of your command and the error?

Comment: the problem was solved. I confused the command with vi and vim. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple:

```
:%substitute~\.~/~g
```